Making face blendshapes with multiple facial hair options
I'm trying to make facial animations for my model, but am trying to think of a way to easily link up facial features to the blendshapes I'm going to make before I start to make it as painless as possible for me at the very beginning.
It's a model where the user will be able to select the cosmetics, so no facial features, mustache, beard, both, etc. Currently they are separate meshes (though if there is no way to make this easier I'll just merge the meshes and do them all manually like that) I'm mainly trying to find a way to link up the vertices and meshes in some sort of way so that making blendshapes for the bare face will also apply to the other facial features.
